# How to restrict Google places search for more than two countries in React Native?

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I am using react-native-google-places but I need to restrict search for 2 or more countries such as Denmark and USA. But in react-native-google-places only option I have is country which takes only a single country country. How I can resolve this issue without using latitude & longitude and radius?

```js
RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal({
            country: 'us', // need to use 'us', 'dk' or somethink like ['us', 'dk']
            useOverlay: true
        })
        .then((place) => {
            console.log(place);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the underlying native APIs on [android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder#setCountry(java.lang.String)) and [ios](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter)
you can only confine your searches to one country at a time.
Not sure about your specific needs but you can probably have a look to [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete), that one uses the Javascript API and you can filter by multiples countries specifying the [components parameter](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests)

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-google-places-autocomplete library, In this we can restrict results for more than one country by adding query parameter like this :

query={{
key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
language: 'en',
components: 'country:us|country:ca',
}}

Comment: Hi, how can i get only streets with the query?

Comment: @MikhaMatta you need to add the `{type: "address"}` field